# I keep getting a warning for multiple build commands regarding .png files for my iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, dependencies

> Warning: Multiple build commands for output file
>   /Users/nroldos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/artistreeApp-fnivhzlzlmkerwhdwwfnelzldkqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/artistreeApp.app/Near_Me@2x.png
>
> Warning: Multiple build commands for output file
>   /Users/nroldos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/artistreeApp-fnivhzlzlmkerwhdwwfnelzldkqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/artistreeApp.app/Search@2x.png
>
> And so on...

Anybody know what these warnings mean? I would try to explain this more but I don't have a clue where these multiple build commands come from. I have only one view controller where I call for these .png files

Answer (score 10):

Xcode complains with this type of warning when it is confused. What happens is that project has more than one files with the same name and Xcode doesn't know which one to compile.

**Solution:** Search for the resource under `Copy Bundle Resources` and remove the duplicate entries.

**Steps:**

1. Open the`Copy Bundle Resources` on `Build Phases` tab.
2. Find duplicate entries of the same files in that list.
3. Delete the duplicate reference.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Abankumov

Answer (score 3):

Open the **Copy Bundle Resources** on **Build Phases** tab. Find duplicate entries of the same files in that list and **Delete** the duplicate references.